How to count duplicate roots of polynomial in MATLAB?
Given coeffitients array and the accuracy tolerance I need to find the roots of a polynomial and also check their accuracy. I wrote this function:
function res = polyroots(varargin)
  coeffs = varargin{1};
  r = roots(coeffs);
  if nargin==2
    eps = varargin{2};
    r = uniquetol(r, eps);
  endif
  r = uniquetol(r);

I wanted to calculate the number of unique roots and based on that determine how many are duplicates but I am not sure how to check for uniqueness if my roots can be complex numbers. Or is there another way to check if there are roots that are the same?
Could somebody please help or give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Are you using Octave rather than MATLAB (endif)?  A few issues with your current code: it’s not a good idea to overload eps and the result from you if is overwritten by the last line.

What is wrong with your current use of uniquetol? – I’m unsure but it looks like from the documentation that complex values would be supported.

@horchler currenly I'm getting this error with the function: error: uniquetol: A must be a real floating point array
